# 10th Anniversary of Software Recommendations SE!

Tags: discussion, featured

In February Software Recommendations SE turned 10 years old. Congratulations on asking, answering, voting, and building this community for a whole decade!

Whenever a Stack Exchange site turns 10 we like to celebrate by encouraging users to reflect on their experiences here.

How did you first discover the site? Do you have a favorite question or answer that helped you solve a problem? A stellar recommendation? Any funny anecdotes or other insights on your time here, that you would like to share? We want to hear it all!

Answer (score 6):

Congratulations Software Recommendations!

This site has been super useful for me, to find out whether a program already exists before developing my own.

Answer (score 5):

> How did you first discover the site?

You just read [all sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites#name) and have a look on which ones you're interested in.

> Do you have a favorite question or answer that helped you solve a problem?

The most surprising answer was [JArchitect](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/35320/ndepend-for-java), a product of a company of which I already owned 2 other programs but their website is so bad that I couldn't find the version for Java.

> A stellar recommendation?

Awesome free / open source programs which I like very much:

- Blender (3D software)
- OBS Studio (screen recording, live streaming)
- Libre Office (office)
- GIMP / Paint.NET (image editing)
- VLC (video playback)
- Firefox (bowser)
- VS Code / Visual Studio Community Edition / PyCharm Community (programming)
- DaVinci Resolve (video editing)
- MuseScore / Audacity (sound)
- FTK Imager Lite (forensics, saved me a dozen of hard disk losses)

> Any funny anecdotes or other insights on your time here, that you would like to share?

I sometimes come here to look for software, just to find an answer that I have written myself. On one hand that's great, on the other hand I feel like I'm getting old.